# How to use texfield extension for restrict user entering special characters?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I want to use UITextField extension for restricting user not to enter special characters.I have used below code but UItextfield does not allow me to define store properties.so i don't know where to define special charecter set.

```
extension UITextField:UITextFieldDelegate {


    var allowSpecialCharecters:Bool {
        get {
            return self.allowSpecialCharecters
        }
        set {
           self.allowSpecialCharecters = newValue
        }
    }



    public func shouldChangeText(in range: UITextRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {


        if !allowSpecialCharecters {

            let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: notAllowedCharacters);
            let inverted = set.inverted;

            let filtered = text.components(separatedBy: inverted).joined(separator: "")
            print("String Filtered: \(filtered)")
            return filtered != text;

        } else {
            return true
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please elaborate a little bit this line "UItextfield does not allow me to define store properties"

Comment: You cannot add stored properties inside extensions. Making a subclass seems like the simplest way to go in this case.

Comment: Create custom class of type UITextField and define property that you want. And then extend the custom class with UITextFieldDelegate and use it wherever you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

First there is a specific method with UITextFieldDelegate allowing or not the user to enter desired caracters :  `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`.

In other words, by implementing this method you can control what the user can enter as characters, numbers...
Here is how I made it with several examples :

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let candidate = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    switch textField.tag {
    //Restrict to only have 2 number digits and max 23 for hours for UITextfields having tags 1, 3, 5 and 7
    case 1, 3, 5, 7:
        return textField.hasHourPattern(in: candidate, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: candidate.characters.count))
    //Restrict to only have 2 number digits and max 59 for minutes fr UITextFields having tags with 2, 4, 6 and 8
    case 2, 4, 6, 8:
        return textField.hasMinutePattern(in: candidate, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: candidate.characters.count))
    //Restrict to have 3 digits max for interger part then . and 2 digits for decimal part for UITextField having tag 9 
    case 9:
        return textField.hasTauxPattern(in: candidate, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: candidate.characters.count))
    default:
        return true
    }
}
```

Then, I extend UITextField class to create my 3 functions to check input expression with **Regular expressions**. I control if the expression entered matches a specific pattern :

```
extension UITextField {
// Patterns function
// If has hour pattern : 0 to 23 include

  func hasHourPattern(in string: String, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], range: NSRange) -> Bool {
    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(?:[0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|)$", options: [])
    return regex?.firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.characters.count)) != nil
  }

// If has minute pattern : 0 to 59 include

  func hasMinutePattern(in string: String, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], range: NSRange) -> Bool {
    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(?:[0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9]|)$", options: [])
    return regex?.firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.characters.count)) != nil
  }

// If has taux pattern : 3 decimals . and 2 decimals

  func hasTauxPattern(in string: String, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions = [], range: NSRange) -> Bool {
    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^\\d{0,3}(\\.\\d{0,2})?$", options: [])
    return regex?.firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.characters.count)) != nil
  }
  ...//Create whatever function to check a pattern you want
}
```

Moreover, you can also with the UITextfield property called `keyboardType` indicates what type of characters you want by displaying the keyboard type needed.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of the **IDIOCY** of the difference between

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView,
       shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
```

and

```
override func shouldChangeText(in range: UITextRange,
       replacementText text: String) -> Bool
```

The second one is a function of the internal `UITextInput` class.

**Stupidly, Xcode will autocomplete THE WRONG ONE for you.**

That wrong function does nothing and is not a delegate of `UITextView` .

The first one is a `UITextViewDelegate`. The first one is the one you want.

```
import UIKit
class Example: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {

    override func .. init {
        super.delegate = self
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        print("This works. Correct delegate function.")
        return true
    }

    // XCODE GIVES YOU THE FOLLOWING AS AN AUTOCOMPLETE:
    // IT IS TOTALLY WRONG:
    override func shouldChangeText(in range: UITextRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        print("Irrelevant badly named function. You will never see this.")
        return super.shouldChangeText(in: range, replacementText: text)
    }
}
```